# Problems with file hooks and permissions in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I run my own GitLab server and setup a file hook which is supposed to access some files in my users directory. The file hook is executed by the `git` user, so I get a `permission denied`.

A certain process `foo`, which places some files in my user directory which the file hook is supposed to read does not give me the option to add another group to the created files.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside:

- [using sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131868/7490), meaning having a sudoers in place, authorizing `git` to copy `foo`'s files
- modifying the [ACL (`setfacl`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131689/7490), to add `git` as an authorized user to read those files

there is no GitLab-specific solution, only Linux-based ones.